# Camel RX - Conditional endpoints

Tags: java, apache-camel, rx-java

I'm trying to refactor some camel routes to use camel-rx instead of camel dsl and I've hit a point where I want to process the events inside an observable but then use the `ReactiveCamel` class to send the observable to an endpoint based on conditions. For example, it would be useful to map my observable to an object with target route information and then use `ReactiveCamel` to send to this target.

Is something like that possible or perhaps another way to implement this use case?